# Mocking OffsetDateTime.now with mockk

Tags: kotlin, mockk

Trying to mock OffsetDateTime.now() with mockk, but it throws

`Missing calls inside every { ... } block`

I tried:

```
staticMockk<OffsetDateTime>().mock().run {
  val mockTime = OffsetDateTime.now()
  every { OffsetDateTime.now() } returns mockTime
  // test
}
```

Also tried:

```
mockkStatic(OffsetDateTime::class)
val mockTime = OffsetDateTime.now()
every { OffsetDateTime.now() } returns mockTime
```

Answer (score 7):

For me it is okay. Please consider using the latest version (1.8.8 or 1.8.8.kotlin13) or if it does not work please report a bug.

Here is my code:

```
mockkStatic(OffsetDateTime::class)

val date = OffsetDateTime.of(
    2012,
    10,
    10,
    10,
    10,
    10,
    10,
    ZoneOffset.UTC
)

every {
    OffsetDateTime.now()
} returns date

println(OffsetDateTime.now())
```