# Mocking ZonedDateTime.now() with mockk ends wtih "io.mockk.MockKException: Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block"

Tags: kotlin, junit5, mockk

I am trying to write some tests for this code:

```
private companion object {
    val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z")
}

fun getSomeValue(): String {
    val dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(config.getSomeDateTime(), formatter)
    return if (dateTime < ZonedDateTime.now()) {
        "A"
    } else {
        "B"
    }
}
```

Here is test which is not working:

```
@Test
fun testGetSomeValue() {
    mockkStatic(ZonedDateTime::class) {
        val mockZDT: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2023, 12, 1, 12, 34, 56, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC"))
        every { ZonedDateTime.now() } returns mockZDT --> exception
        every { config.getSomeDateTime() } returns "2023-05-01 01:23:45 UTC"
        service.getSomeValue() shouldBe "A"
    }
}
```

Output from test is:

```
io.mockk.MockKException: Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is mock
```

I have been looking for solution across internet and some places says it should work (i.e. [OffsetDateTime issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52563205/mocking-offsetdatetime-now-with-mockk).

On the other hand when I use Mockito solution with "mockStatic" from mockito-inline I have no issues. But this is a code I have inherited and need to make small change request, so I don't want to add additional dependency.

I am using:

- mockk 1.13.5

Comment: Setting the issue aside, it's rather unnecessary to use mockk here, unless `now()` is used by some code that you cannot control. java.time already gives you the `Clock` class. Just give `now()` a custom `Clock`. See [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70109242/5133585) for an example.

Comment: Is your `config` a mock?

Comment: @k314159 yes, but test fails before it is set up. Works fine when I mock ZonedDateTime with Mockito.

Comment: What do you mean by "test fails before it is set up"? The config object in `every { config.getSomeDateTime() } returns ...` needs to be mocked before you call `every`.

Comment: It is mocked. Returns mocked value when using Mockito for ZonedDateTime.

Answer (score 0):

The following sample code is a complete, reproducible test that passes:

```
import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockk
import io.mockk.mockkStatic
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import java.time.ZoneId
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

class MyTest {
    interface Config {
        fun getSomeDateTime(): String
    }

    class Service(private val config: Config) {
        private companion object {
            val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z")
        }

        fun getSomeValue(): String {
            val dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(config.getSomeDateTime(), formatter)
            return if (dateTime < ZonedDateTime.now()) {
                "A"
            } else {
                "B"
            }
        }
    }

    val config = mockk<Config>()

    val service = Service(config)

    @Test
    fun testGetSomeValue() {
        mockkStatic(ZonedDateTime::class) {
            val mockZDT: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2023, 12, 1, 12, 34, 56, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC"))
            every { ZonedDateTime.now() } returns mockZDT
            every { config.getSomeDateTime() } returns "2023-05-01 01:23:45 UTC"
            service.getSomeValue() shouldBe "A"
        }
    }
}
```

Versions: Mockk 1.13.8, Kotlin 1.9.21, JVM target 21.

To make it work on a recent JVM, you need to apply the workaround detailed in https://mockk.io/doc/md/jdk16-access-exceptions.html.